# Amaterasu particle's secondary particles travel faster than the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, atmospheric-science, cosmic-rays, cherenkov-radiation

From [this article in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/nov/24/amaterasu-extremely-high-energy-particle-detected-falling-to-earth)

*When ultra-high-energy cosmic rays hit Earth’s atmosphere, they initiate a cascade of secondary particles and electromagnetic radiation in what is known as an extensive air shower.
**Some charged particles in the air shower travel faster than the speed of light**, producing a type of electromagnetic radiation that can be detected by specialised instruments.*

I'm not a physicist but this seems rather unlikely to me.

Comment: speed of light in the air is lesser than the speed of light in the vacuum.

Comment: Check out [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation)

Answer (score 1):

This is not fundamentally impossible. It is the speed of light in the vacuum that cannot be exceeded. Speed of light in the air (and the article says **in the air**) is also very high but it can be exceeded by such a monster particle as Amaterasu.